# Looking for tutorial on how to use gmaps autocomplete with rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, ggmap

I'm trying to add autocomplete using the gmaps api within my rails 4 project but as a newcomer I lack of knowledge in the matter.. Does anyone would have links to a good tutorial about gmaps autocomplete api and rails 4 ?

Many thanks

Comment: as far i know, there is no autocomplete plugin with gmap, since js is framework independant you can follow steps from google map api developer site https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems you are looking for [geocomplete](https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete).Its very easy to use and You get autocomplete(places names) features in your textbox....take a look at these [examples](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/).
you will get a **map**,**customize markers** and **some dynamic features** as well

for example,

```
   //initialize the map
   $("addressTextBox").geocomplete();
```

Git url - https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete

...HOPE THIS HELPS

Comment: The link that @Milind provides is actually to the geocomplete jQuery library, not the gem. The gem, which wraps the jQuery library, can be found here: https://github.com/guyisra/geocomplete_rails

Comment: Are there any maintained solutions? This solution is no longer maintained.

Comment: The new one uses Reactjs, you can use it but there are few changes but its still easy to set up and use.